# Conta de Armazenamento Azure - Subdomínio com SSL

Tags: microsoft-azure, blob, armazenamento

Eu criei uma conta de armazenamento na *Azure*. As Contas de Armazenamento da Azure permite que invés de usar a URL deles *`NOME_da_CONTA.blob.core.windows.net`* eu use um subdomínio *`SUB.meusite.com`*.

As URLs da própria Azure vem com *SSL(https)*, mas quando eu uso o subdomínio só vem como http.

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Olá André seja bem vindo, é interessante dá uma lidinha no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona as regras do site.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui possui um artigo explicando como [configurar um nome de domínio personalizado para seu ponto de extremidade de Armazenamento de Blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/).

Porém, para domínio próprio, você terá que comprar seu próprio certificado de SSL para seu próprio domínio. Senão irá funcionar apenas como HTTP, e não HTTPS.